# Пишу чат на vue js,есть ли пакет или пример кода - для звукового оповещения?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, поиск-библиотек

То есть при срабатывании события о получении сообщения обрабатывало звуковое оповещение ?

Comment: это вам в гугл надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const audio = new Audio('Мало_половин.mp3');

if (audio) {
    audio.play();
}
```